# Why is $(X, \mathcal{C}^*)$ totally bounded?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $(X, \mathcal{T})$ is a Tychonoff space and $\mathcal{C}^*$ is the initial uniformity for the source of all continuous functions from $X$ to $[0,1]$. This is probably something trivial, but why is $(X, \mathcal{C}^*)$ totally bounded?

In general, I know that a uniform space $(X, \mathcal{U})$ is totally bounded iff every ultrafilter is a Cauchyfilter. Should I use this result to prove what I need or is there an easier way?

Comment: Consider the uniform space $Y := [0,1]^{\mathscr{C}(X,[0,1])}$. It's compact, and hence totally bounded. Consider the map $e \colon X \to Y$ given by $\pi_f(e(x)) = f(x)$. Let $Z = e(X)$, and $\mathcal{Z}$ the subspace uniform structure (i.e. the initial uniform structure with respect to the inclusion $Z \subset Y$). As a subspace of a totally bounded space, $(Z,\mathcal{Z})$ is totally bounded. But $\mathcal{C}^{\ast}$ is the initial uniform structure induced from $\mathcal{Z}$ by the bijection [$\mathcal{T}$ is Tíkhonov] $e \colon X \xrightarrow{\sim} Z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the question, we will use that the uniform space $(X, \mathcal{C}^*)$ is totally bounded iff every ultrafilter is a Cauchyfilter. Also, we have a nice characterisation of Tychonoff spaces: $(X, \mathcal{T})$ is Tychonoff iff the source of all continuous functions from $X$ to $[0,1]$ is initial.

Let $\mathcal{U}$ be an ultrafilter in $(X, \mathcal{C}^*)$. Then $\text{stack} f(\mathcal{U})$ is ultra in $[0,1]$ for every continuous function $f$ from $X$ to $[0,1]$. But since $[0,1]$ is compact, $\text{stack} f(\mathcal{U})$ converges and is thus a Cauchyfilter. Using the initiality of the source, we get that $\mathcal{U}$ is a Cauchyfilter and we are done.

Answer (score 1):

For each finite $F\subseteq C(X,[0,1])$ and $\epsilon>0$ let

$$D_\epsilon(F)=\{\langle x,y\rangle\in X\times X:|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon\text{ for each }f\in F\}\;;$$

the sets $D_\epsilon(F)$ form a base for $\mathscr{C}^*$. For each such $F$ and $\epsilon$ there is a finite $H_\epsilon(F)\subseteq[0,1]$ such that

$$[0,1]\subseteq\bigcup_{u\in H_\epsilon(F)}B\left(u,\frac{\epsilon}2\right)\;.$$

Let $F=\{f_1,\ldots,f_n\}$. For each $\mathbf{u}=\langle u_1,\ldots,u_n\rangle\in H_\epsilon(F)^n$ let

$$U_\epsilon(F,\mathbf{u})=\bigcap_{k=1}^nf_k^{-1}\left[B\left(u_k,\frac{\epsilon}2\right)\right]\;,$$

an open set in $X$. If $\langle x,y\rangle\in U_\epsilon(F,\mathbf{u})\times U_\epsilon(F,\mathbf{u})$, then

$$|f_k(x)-f_k(y)|\le|f_k(x)-f_k(u_k)|+|f_k(u_k)-f_k(y)|<\frac{\epsilon}2+\frac{\epsilon}2=\epsilon$$

for $k=1,\ldots,n$, so

$$\bigcup_{\mathbf{u}\in H_\epsilon(F)^n}\big(U_\epsilon(F,\mathbf{u})\times U_\epsilon(F,\mathbf{u})\big)\subseteq D_\epsilon(F)\;.$$

Finally, it’s clear that for each $x\in X$, there is a $\mathbf{u}\in H_\epsilon(F)^n$ such that $x\in U_\epsilon(F,\mathbf{u})$, so

$$\{U_\epsilon(F,\mathbf{u}):\mathbf{u}\in H_\epsilon(F)^n\}$$

is a finite open cover of $X$, and it follows that $\mathscr{C}^*$ is [totally bounded](http://planetmath.org/totallyboundeduniformspace).